# What happened to ZIP RAM?

Tags: hardware, amiga, memory

I have several retro machines and add-on cards for the Amiga that use [ZIP RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zig-zag_in-line_package). This vertically mounted chip design enjoyed a brief popularity in the early 1990s, in between the original DIP DRAM and the rise of the SIMM memory.

The advantage with ZIP over DIP was obvious - more RAM chips in the same board area. Of course, you needed different sockets.

SIMM offered the same space advantage, but with a more complicated socket and with the RAM chips having to be soldered onto a PCB. Overall, seems like a more costly way to go than ZIP RAM, but SIMM obviously won in the market.

So why were the added manufacturing costs for SIMMs not an issue and why did they quickly replace ZIPs?

**Note:** I get that SIMM insertion and removal is relatively easy, but that ease-of-upgrade option only makes sense if it was a major consumer selling point. My recollection is that most motherboard RAM upgrades happened at the point-of-sale, with vendors likely choosing the cheapest solution.

Comment: What is "ZIP" RAM?

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson It's a different form of packaging. Looks like a DIP DRAM chip flipped on its side, having the pins on the side of the package rather than the bottom. So the chips stick up higher but occupy much less space on the PCB.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson See the image in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ECE/comments/a4slev/semiconductor_inline_packages_have_oddly/) for comparison of **DIP** (dual-in-line), **SIP** (single-in-line) and **ZIP** (zig-zag-in-line) packages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ZIP package was mostly replaced by better packages.  Ignoring for a moment the variety of memory modules (DIMM etc) most memories moved to SOP, SOIC, TSOP or BGA for higher pin density, improved mechanical stability and lower package height.

None of the new packages suffer from the bending torsion that made ZIP packages prone to damage. Further they do not require the package to maintain the complex bending of pins that ZIP requires.

All of these result in lower manufacturing costs and fewer system failures.

Could you imagine trying to do a Raspberry PI with ZIP memory? Me neither.

Comment: I think this answers what _really_ happened: SMD packages.

Comment: The Question is about SIMM modules, not is a single boarder with soldered on RAM like the RasPI, so there's not relation to what was asked - and more important, SIMM do predate the use of SMD RAMs in PCs - 30 pin, as well as 72 pin ones where fitted with various kinds of DIP RAM in the begining: commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Edoram.jpg

Comment: @Raffzahn Actually the question is about ZIP packages. The image in your comment shows surface mounted SOJ packages on a memory module. No DIP packages anywhere. Here's a link: https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/517/VG2617405EJ-6.php

Comment: @PeterCamilleri You may want to reread, as the question is about why ZIP has been replaced by SIMM. Next, SOJ ust still a DIP format with inbound bend pins - but more important, just pointing that out doesn't change the primary point, that SIMM was introduced with thruhole components, not SMD - check the very next picture from wiki ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMM#/media/File:Atari_STE_256kB_RAM_1.jpg ) - saves me posting a picture of several shoeboxes of DIP SIMM in my workshop :))

Comment: @Raffzahn The [first SIMMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMM#History) were apparently developed for flip-chip and SMT (J-lead) technology. While through-hole was made, I believe that the intent was always allow DRAM to go to SMT.

Comment: @user71659 The SIMMs your link mentions are not SIMMs as seen today, but RAM chips packaged as SIP module using pins to be plugged into standard spaced sockets. While they can be rightful seen as a development step among memory modules, their development was a dead end. They are not realy related to the development of prevailing SIMMs made as PCB with edge contacts and fiting slots/sockets. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIPP_memory

Comment: @Raffzahn The point is that even the predecessors of SIMMs were designed for SMT.

Comment: @user71659 Sorry, I just fail to see the relevance of any 'intention' here. The average SIMM of the late 80s/early 90s was DIP based, which clearly proves that SMD was **not** the main (nor any) reason to switch for SIMMs. The switch happened independant of the existance of SMD RAM devices.

Comment: @Raffzahn: A computer store in Madison used to give away surplus 256Kx8 SIMMs as keyrings, and a lot of students had them.  I noticed that most students' keyrings were missing chips, though, so I made a point of selecting one of the DIP-based ones.  The attachment point of the ring eventually broke, but the chips all stayed on the module for as long as I was using it.

Comment: This reminds me of the Mac. Upgrading one from 128k to 512k required soldering on a four layer board. 30-pin SIMMs used in the Mac Plus can be made on two layers which was easier to solder on even in the days where DIP 1Mbit DRAM chips was more common. In general only very early SIMMs was DIP based, once the DRAM shortage went away in 1989 everyone switched.

Comment: The transition to SMT itself is important BTW because of the rise of x8 and x16 DRAM chips. SOJ sockets for those not using SIMMs are common and easy to make too.

Answer (score 25):

Right off the top, SIMM type modules have higher pin densities and are mechanically far more robust than that ZIP chip package. It'd be relatively easy to bend pins getting these things in an out (possibly worse than DIPs even), and protecting the pins in transport looks even harder than doing so with DIP chips.

Remember that many retailers are unlikely to admit to having broken the pin off a chip - they'll return it as defective instead.

Further, each ZIP is one chip, no more, no less. With a SIMM module being a PCB with chips mounted on it, you can build modules in various ways to get the desired density and to use the most cost effective parts available at the time.

In the end, as busses widenened, the advantages of being able to use multiple chips probably were the final determinant.

Comment: Zip is far worse than DIP IMHO, I have had some that had broken pins, some that had bent up pins, and if something doesn't work, it is extremely hard to see where the problem is. And, they are a nuisance to plug in correctly.

Comment: Speaking from personal experience, when I fitted sixteen ZIP chips to upgrade an Acorn A420/1, I managed to break pins on two chips in the process: that's an 11% failure rate for a first-time user (who's experienced in handling DIP chips). Luckily, I'd bought a batch of 20, so I had spares.

Comment: And I've gotten a few chips labeled new that had bent pens already in the box. Shenanigans.

Answer (score 16):

Separate memory modules on a standardized interface provide several advantages:

- Reduced overall production cost
- Greater flexibility in RAM selection
- expansion way beyond what a classic (pre-SIMM) motherboard would support.
- Reduced motherboard design cost
- Greatly reduced motherboard production cost
- Faster innovation cycles due to defined and spacious interface definition
- Move of RAM choice and investment to point of sales (or later)
- More option and reduced investment for retailers.
- Modules will be usable across different brands and boards.

And maybe most important

- Greatly reduced cost of memory cards (in addition to reduced mainboard cost)

---

> The advantage with ZIP over DIP was obvious - more RAM chips in the same board area. Of course, you needed different sockets.

That's why it was added, and especially used in graphics cards, where space was always a premium - at least when trying to provide upper end features - And RAM was (more often than not) already provided in full with the card.

> SIMM offered the same space advantage, but with a more complicated socket and with the RAM chips having to be soldered onto a PCB. Overall, seems like a more costly way to go than ZIP RAM, but SIMM obviously won in the market.

Not really, as it reduced the amount of parts. Instead of having a socket for each and every ram chip a single socket was needed holding 8 (or sometimes up to 32) chips. Quite a reduction from the point of a motherboard manufacturer. The memory modules itself could carry the chips without any socket. Further it allowed to separate RAM mounting technology (thruhole or SMD) from motherboard manufacturing. A SIMM Module could use any kind of RAM, no matter if it is DIP, SIP, ZIP or SMD like TQFP or BGA.

It further decoupled RAM pinout from motherboard layout. Now larger or smaller RAMs from various manufacturers could be incorporated. This include pinouts that were not known/available at the point the motherboard was designed.

And most important, it removed the need to design a motherboard for a specific amount of memory and, as follow up, the design of specific memory cards. A motherboard can only hold sockets for a specific amount of RAM of a specific pinout. When they are filled, some kind of memory or I/O bus card must be made to add more memory.

Using memory modules is, well, modularization. Much like having a nice, clear API, designed with  an upgrade path in mind allows independent development and sales.

> So why were the added manufacturing costs for SIMMs not an issue and why did they quickly replace ZIPs?

Because manufacturing costs were not higher but lower. Lower for all parties involved, Motherboard and RAM module manufacturers as well as retailers.

- On the motherboard side, buying one (complex) socket is less expensive then adding 32 (or more) single chip sockets.
- Similar, placing one (or even 4) SIMM sockets is faster and less expensive than 32 separate sockets.
- For the RAM manufacturer the board design will be way less expensive than for a traditional (large) memory expansion board (like ISA Memory cards for the PC).
- Similar board production will cost **way** less.
- For the retailer taking the RAM (socket/space) cost out of the motherboard reduces upfront investment on motherboards, as well as on RAM modules

> Note: I get that SIMM insertion and removal is relatively easy, but that ease-of-upgrade option only makes sense if it was a major consumer selling point. My recollection is that most motherboard RAM upgrades happened at the point-of-sale, with vendors likely choosing the cheapest solution.

The profit of vendors/resellers configuring a PC is quite dependent on the time invested to configure a PC to the customers specs, and inserting 8, 16 or more flimsy ZIP chips without bending a pin and good insertion and so on, is a great burden compared with clipping in one or two SIMMs. Time is money.

Stock cost is as well important for a vendor/reseller.  Modularized structure does enable a considerable lower stock by only holding a few different memory modules instead of many different chips and even more model specific memory expansion boards.

Comment: Another format my first 80386 machine used was, IIRC, SIP.  A circuit board which plugged into IIRC a 30-pin inline socket and was electrically equivalent to a SIMM.  I think SIP sockets were a tiny bit cheaper than SIMM sockets, but the cost difference would have been eaten up by the extra assembly cost of putting the pins on the board.

Comment: @supercat Jup, that SIP (BTW, there are also SIP chips) 'socket' for memory boards was added out of the same considerations - they just not went for improving a card edge format (as SIMM is) but used the more reliable (and proven) pin and socket mechanics. Another argument I heared for them (back then) was that these modules could also be soldered in for a factory installed memory, saving the sockets in total. SIMMs did beat them already in the short run by their ove all lower price.

Comment: Don't forget the improved troubleshooting and repair times. Especially important in the production to lower those times.

Comment: One problem worth noting however is that 30-pin SIMM PCBs was two layers, but by the time of SDRAM the DIMM PCBs were already six layer.

Comment: The traces are also much easier to draw and route.